# I'm trying to take a screenshot of the entire screen, and then resize a webview. The webview refuses to resize

Tags: ios, uiwebview, resize

I have a webview, and when a user clicks on a link, the app takes a screenshot of the screen, and then loads the page, and then when the page is done, the image is removed from the screen.

I also need the webview to resize while the image is visible.

With the code to make the image in place, the webview won't resize anymore. If I take out the code to make the image, the webview does resize. However, with the code to make the image, it DOES move the webview up to the correct origin, but it does not then make the webview larger. Here is my code. It starts running the instant the user clicks on a link:

```
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1024, 768));
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


        if (!_coverImageView) _coverImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
        _coverImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f , 0.0f, 1024.0f, 768.0f);
        _coverImageView.image = viewImage;
        [self.view addSubview:_coverImageView];

        _webView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f , 0.0f, 1024.0f, 768.0f);
```

Then, when the webview is finished loading:

```
        [_coverImageView removeFromSuperview];
```

I'm completely lost as to how this affects my webview. So again, this code does successfully take the image, put it on the screen, and then MOVE the webview up, but it does not resize the webview.

Comment: Are you using auto layout? If so, you shouldn't be setting a new frame for the web view, you should be adjusting constraints. When the view needs to be redrawn, like when you call removeFromSuperview, the web view's frame will revert to the frame defined by its constraints, not the new frame you defined.

Comment: That was it! Thank you. If you want to type this into an actual response I can give you a correct answer if you like.